# Regular expression in "CREATE TABLE"

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the following problem: I want to create a table Client with his id and name. I also want to check if the Name field contains only letters. Here is my query:

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENT(
ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, 
FIRST_NAME CHAR(10) CONSTRAINT NAME_CHECK CHECK(REGEXP_LIKE(FIRST_NAME, '^[A-Za-z]*$'))
);
```

The script works just fine, table is being created. But the following INSERT statement

`INSERT INTO CLIENT
VALUES(1, 'BOB');`

doesn't work. Here is the error text:

```
INSERT INTO CLIENT
VALUES(1, 'BOB')
Error report -
ORA-02290: check constraint (TASK8.NAME_CHECK) violated
```

I'm sure that the reason of this mistake is quite obvious, but I just don't understand it. I have never had problems with regular expressions before.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that the issue is spaces.  `CHAR()` data types are automatically padded with spaces to the length.

For this reason, variable length strings are used much more often than fixed-length strings.  In Oracle, that would be a `VARCHAR2()` type:

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENT (
    ID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, 
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(10) CONSTRAINT NAME_CHECK CHECK (REGEXP_LIKE(FIRST_NAME, '^[A-Za-z]*$'))
);
```

I can add a few more notes:

- I'm a strong fan of the primary key being `clientId` or `client_id` in this case, rather than the generic `id`.  This allows most foreign key references to use exactly the same name.
- 10 characters is too short for a first name.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Now everything works.  Thank you so much)

Comment: And thanks for your notes, I will keep that in mind.